# Using OData service with SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, odata

I am trying to test using OData with SharePoint and simply trying to query the calendar list. however whenever I try to query the following URL:

```
http://MyDomain/MySite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Calendar
```

I get redirected to:

```
http://MyDomain/MySite/_layouts/error.aspx?ErrorText=virtualPath
```

This kindly tells me "An error has occurred on the server." Which gives me no indication of what the problem might be or how to fix it. Does anyone with more experience with OData and/or SharePoint know what could be going on and how to fix it?

I am relatively new to OData and SharePoint so it may just be my ignorance that is getting in my way. My first inclination was to check to see if the OData services are enabled, but I see no way to enable or disable the OData services and my Google searches on the topic have come up empty thus far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Luis, I found the problem. I had been told the server was SharePoint 2010 when I started working with it. However I found it's actually SharePoint 2007, which does not support OData. So now all the errors make sense, I just wish SharePoint could have given me a better error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed:

ADO.NET Data Services Update for .NET 3.5 SP1.

Check here:

http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/03/26/could-not-load-type-idataserviceupdateprovider-when-using-rest-with-sharepoint-2010/